# Требовать с кого-то или от кого-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Подскажите, пожалуйста, могу ли я требовать **с** мужа? Или только **от** мужа?

Comment: Требовать только "от мужа", разумеется. "С мужа" можно пылинки сдувать, например. :)

Comment: @freim боюсь, вы опять ошибаетесь. С паршивой овцы можно требовать шести клок. Муж - грамматически - та же овца. Так что с него можно что-то требовать, если оно на нем. Волосы, например, - по аналогии с овцой.

Answer (score 1):

В [словаре управления](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) утверждается, что говорить *требовать **с кого-то*** можно (вариант является самым обычным, не просторечным — пометка отсутствует).

**требовать** [в разных значениях]
1. *кого-чего.* Требовать учителя; Требовать внимания; Требовать объяснений у провинившегося сотрудника; Требовать правдивого отражения жизни в литературе.
2. *что* (редко; при конкретизации объекта). Требовать свою зарплату; Требовать взятую из библиотеки книгу; Требовать пропуск; Требовать одолженные деньги.
**3.** ***от*** кого / **у** кого. Требовать от учеников; Он требовал у меня пропуск. См. [**от — у**](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/1507/%D0%BE%D1%82_%E2%80%94_%D1%83).
**4.** ***с*** кого. *Требовать квартплату **с** жильцов.*

Мне думается, что выбор предлога зависит от конкретной ситуации — от того, *что именно* вы требуете.

Требовать повышенные алименты с бывшего мужа.
Требовать с мужа достойное содержание.
*В детсаду **с** родителей требовали деньги за проведение новогоднего утренника.*

Считаю, что такое употребление предлога «с» вполне литературно. (Встречается оно, правда, довольно редко.)

**Дополнение** (М. А. Булгаков. Записки покойника):
*Впрочем, что же **требовать с человека,** который через два дня после того, как поставил точку в конце записок, кинулся с Цепного моста вниз головой.*

Answer (score 0):

В нормативной речи - только от мужа.

"С мужа", в литературном языке вы можете требовать разве что прядь волос. Даже шубу - и ту только **с его плеча**, а не с него.

Другое дело, что в просторечии такая форма "требовать с кого" в значении "от кого" существует весьма активно. Возможно, что под влиянием украинского.

(+)
И еще. Забыл сразу написать.
Есть такой глагол "стребовать". Лопатин считает его просто сниженным, но Кузнецов поднимает уже до разговорного. Вот с ним интереснее. Он-то управляет именно с предлогом "с". То есть "стребовать чего-то с мужа" - уже и не ошибка.
И это несколько расшатывает стройность сказанного ранее в отношении формы "требовать с". Возможно, что и за ней когда-нибудь признают право на существование. Но это дело будущего. Пока такая форма ненормативна.